# How can I create setup ssh so that I don't need to re-enter my password everytime?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

On Ubuntu, I often need to ssh to a server. 
How can I setup my ssh in my ubuntu so that I don't need to enter my password everytime I ssh to that server?

Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/271107/passwordless-ssh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Ubuntu desktops will start an SSH Agent for you automatically.  So you should really be looking at using agent based authentication.  Basically you create a keypair, and publish an SSH key to the remote system, and on the local system use `ssh-add` to make Ubuntu recognize your key for a given session.

- Generate a keypair with [ssh-keygen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen).
- Copy your public key to remote systems with [ssh-copy-id](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id).
- Add your private key to the agent with [ssh-add](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-add).